# My chat app does not work other that wifi connection

Tags: android, performance

I have given user permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

chat app works well with wifi but it doesn't work with GSM connection.

http://pastie.org/9776176 i wrote the database connection code.

Comment: Are you facing any error, does your app crashes when you are connected to internet via GSM connection ?

Comment: no error it give it doesn't event connect to services..

Comment: connect your device with **adb** and try to see the **log** after opening your chat app. I guess it is the GSM delay if your app is not crashing.

Comment: no it simply doesn't respond..